# Is it possible to show current website transfer inside a div?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

is it possible to show the transfer used by my website?
When my visitors visit my page, it will show from beginning how much data (mb/kb) they used to load my website?

Comment: There is no trivial way to get this unless you wrote back end code to look up each resource used in page and get it's file size there

Comment: Using a tool like `cURL` could do this with php...

Comment: What makes this important? Are  you the streaming or something like that?

Comment: I want to use it for my mobile website to show people that the page takes almost no transfer.